# .htaccess problems on phplinkdirectory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have just installed phplinkdirectoy.

I can view the home page fine.

But when I go to any other page I get a 500 server error.

I believe this is due to problems with my .htaccess file, as if I delete the .htaccess file I get a 404 error when going to anything other than the home page.

As an example, part of my .htaccess file looks like this:

```
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
   RewriteRule ^submit$ index.php?controller=submit [QSA,NC,L]
```

I have tried making it look at the install directory on my server by changing it to this:

```
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
   RewriteRule ^submit$ /other_sites/abc.example.com/index.php?controller=submit [QSA,NC,L]
```

n.b.  /other_sites/abc.example.com/ is where the files are stored on my godaddy hosting account.  The url of the directory is actually dir.gingercatgames.com

What am I doing wrong with my .htaccess file?

Update:  The full .htaccess file is here:

```
#######################################################
## PHP Link Directory 5.x - Apache Server Settings ##
#######################################################
# Disable directory browsing
#Options -Indexes

# Follow symbolic links in this directory
#Options +FollowSymLinks

# Override PHP settings that cannot be changed at runtime
# (If your server supports PHP settings via htaccess you can comment following two lines off)
# php_value register_globals   0
# php_value session.auto_start 0

# Customized error messages
# ( If you are running in a subfolder please add it, example: "directory/index.php?httpstatus=404" )
#ErrorDocument 404 index.php?httpstatus=404

# Set the default handler
DirectoryIndex index.php

# URL rewrite rules
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On

   #Make sure RewriteBase points to the directory where you installed phpLD.
   #Example: "/phpld" if your installation is in a "phpld" subdirectory.

   #RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
      RewriteRule ^contactlisting index.php?controller=details&action=contactlisting [QSA,NC,L]
   ##Old Details Link Page Rewrite

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
   RewriteRule (.*)detail/(.*)$ index.php?controller=system&action=detailsredirect&id=$2 [QSA,NC,L]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
   RewriteRule ^detail.php index.php?controller=system&action=detailsredirect&id=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

   ##alphameric Page Rewrite
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
   RewriteRule ^alphameric/([A-Za-z]|0\-9)$ index.php?controller=alphameric&id=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

   ##Author Page Rewrite
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
   RewriteRule ^contact index.php?controller=contact [QSA,NC,L]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
   RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+) index.php?controller=search&action=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
   RewriteRule ^search index.php?controller=search [QSA,NC,L]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
   RewriteRule ^latest index.php?controller=index&action=latest [QSA,NC,L]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
   RewriteRule ^top index.php?controller=index&action=top [QSA,NC,L]

   #RSS
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
   RewriteRule ^rss index.php?controller=index&action=rss [QSA,NC,L]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
   RewriteRule ^user/thankyou$ index.php?controller=user&action=thankyou [QSA,NC,L]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
   RewriteRule ^user/confirmed$ index.php?controller=user&action=confirmed [QSA,NC,L]


   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
   RewriteRule ^user/sendpassword$ index.php?controller=user&action=sendpassword [QSA,NC,L]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
   RewriteRule ^user/recovered$ index.php?controller=user&action=recovered [QSA,NC,L]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
   RewriteRule ^submit$ index.php?controller=submit [QSA,NC,L]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
   RewriteRule ^submit/confirmed$ index.php?controller=submit&action=confirmed [QSA,NC,L]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
   RewriteRule ^payment/([^/?]+) index.php?controller=payment&action=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}  [QSA,NC,L]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
   RewriteRule ^payment index.php?controller=payment [QSA,NC,L]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
   RewriteRule ^user/submissions$ index.php?controller=user&action=submissions [QSA,NC,L]


   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
   RewriteRule ^user/register$ index.php?controller=user&action=register

   ##Author Page Rewrite
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
   RewriteRule ^login$ index.php?controller=user&action=login

   ##Author Page Rewrite
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
   RewriteRule ^logout index.php?controller=user&action=logout

   ##Author Page Rewrite
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
   RewriteRule ^user/profile index.php?controller=user&action=profile

    ##Author Page Rewrite
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
   RewriteRule ^user/([^/?]+) index.php?controller=user&action=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}

   ##Author Page Rewrite
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
   RewriteRule ^user index.php?controller=user&action=index

   ##Author Page Rewrite
  # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  # RewriteRule ^article/(.*)$ index.php?controller=article&idArticle=$1 [QSA,NC]


   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
   RewriteRule ^tag/(.*)$ index.php?controller=tag&tag=$1 [QSA,NC]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
   RewriteRule ^location/([\ 0-9a-zA-Z,_-]*)/(.*) index.php?controller=location&location=$1&category=$2 [QSA,NC]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
   RewriteRule ^location/(.*)$ index.php?controller=location&location=$1 [QSA,NC]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
   RewriteRule ^listing/comment/([0-9]*)$ index.php?controller=details&action=comment&idLink=$1 [QSA,NC]


   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
   RewriteRule ^listing/rate/([0-9]*)$ index.php?controller=details&action=rate&idLink=$1 [QSA,NC]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
   RewriteRule ^listing/(.*)/(.*)([/]*)$ index.php?controller=details&idLink=$2 [QSA,NC]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
   RewriteRule ^listing/(.*)/(.*)([/]*)$ index.php?controller=details&idLink=$2 [QSA,NC]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
   RewriteRule ^rules([0-9]*)$ index.php?controller=index&action=rules [QSA,NC]


   ##Author Page Rewrite
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
   RewriteRule (.*)authors/author-(.*)\.htm[l]?$ index.php?controller=author&action=index&idUser=$2 [QSA,NC]

   ##Owner Page Rewrite
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
   RewriteRule (.*)owner/owner-(.*)\.htm[l]?$ index.php?controller=author&action=index&idUser=$2 [QSA,NC]

   ##Pagination Rewrite
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
   RewriteRule ^page/(.*)([/]*)$  index.php?controller=page&action=index&name=$1 [QSA,NC,L]


   RewriteRule ^(.*)loadingAnimation.gif$ javascripts/thickbox/loadingAnimation.gif


      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
      RewriteRule ^tellfriend index.php?controller=details&action=tellfriend [QSA,NC,L]

      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
      RewriteRule ^unauthorized index.php?controller=index&action=unauthorized [QSA,NC,L]

      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
      RewriteRule ^banned-massage index.php?controller=index&action=banned [QSA,NC,L]

      ##Old Details Link Page Rewrite
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
      RewriteRule ^detail/(.*)-([0-9]*)[\..*] index.php?controller=system&action=detailsredirect&id=$2 [QSA,NC,L]

 ## Domain.com/{link-type}/{title-of-link}-{link-id}.{html|.htm|.php}
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
   RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)([/]*)\.(.*)$ index.php?controller=details&idLink=$2 [QSA,NC,L]

   ## Domain.com/{link-type}/{title-of-link}-{link-id}
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
   RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)([/]*)$ index.php?controller=details&idLink=$2 [QSA,NC,L]


   ## Domain.com/{title-of-link}-{link-id}.{html|.htm|.php}
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
   RewriteRule ^(.*)([/]*)\.(.*)$ index.php?controller=details&idLink=$1 [QSA,NC,L]  

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
   RewriteRule ^detail.php index.php?controller=system&action=detailsredirect&id=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

   ##Pages redirect
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !page-[0-9]+\.html?$
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
   RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ index.php?controller=page&name=$1 [NC,QSA,L]


   ##Category redirect
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]

</IfModule>

#<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
#    MaxRequestLen 1000000000
#    IPCConnectTimeout 100
#    IPCCommTimeout 1000
#</IfModule>
```

Comment: Where is your .htaccess located?

Comment: In the root folder of my website.  i.e. http://dir.gingercatgames.com/.htaccess

Comment: Can you create a file called `info.php` with this code `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and then open `http://dir.gingercatgames.com/info.php` to check what is its `DOCUMENT_ROOT` value.

Comment: It is this:  /var/chroot/home/content/28/5355428/html
Somehow I am not getting the Server errors anymore, but the login doesn't work for the site.  I am now unsure whether or not it is a .htaccess issue or something else!

Comment: If your comment out this rule then will that make login work?

Comment: Which rule do I need to comment out?  It has also returned to 404 errors. ;{

Comment: Can you post your complete .htaccess in question.

Comment: OK.  Thanks for the help anubhava.  I have posted the full file.

Comment: It has finally started to work.  Though I am not sure which version I am on.  All I did was uncomment out #RewriteBase /

Comment: Dear @Ginger are you find the solution.If then please guide me.My url changes but show the index page not goes to the desired page.Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

The  `500` error sounds like either the result of a Multiviews setting, or not having `mod-rewrite` enabled in htaccess.

Try adding this at the top of your original `htaccess`:

```
Options -Multiviews
```

Also check that `mod_rewrite` is **both** installed **and** activated for htaccess files. 
If you are not sure, to check if mod_rewrite is installed, look at the list of installed modules in the output of `phpinfo();`
By default, mod_rewrite is not enabled for htaccess files. If you are managing your own server, open `httpd.conf`
and make sure that the webroot directory block contains one of these lines: `AllowOverride FileInfo` or `AllowOverride All`

Comment: THanks for the tip zx81.  I tried adding Options -Multiviews.  But it did not help.

I tried checking phpinfo for mod_rewrite, but can't see it there.  However, I think it is installed and working correctly as I have Drupal installed in another folder and that seems to be using it successfully.  My phpinfo file is http://dir.gingercatgames.com/phpinfo.php